# how can I reset linked list in c?

Tags: c

this function calculate the difference between two list. Is there a way to 
refresh the second list for example with a command as rewind(with files)?

```
LINK diffIns(LINK lis,LINK lis2){

    LINK p,head,tail;
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
    int trovato=0;
    if(lis==NULL && lis2==NULL){return NULL;}
    while(lis!=NULL){
        trovato=0;
        while(lis2!=NULL && trovato==0){
            if(strcmp(lis->d.targa,lis2->d.targa)==0){
                trovato=1;
            }
            else{
                trovato=0;
            }
            lis2=lis2->next;
        }
        if(trovato==0){
            p=newnode();
            p->d=lis->d;
            p->next=NULL;
            if(head==NULL){head=p; tail=p;}
            else{tail->next=p;tail=p;}
        }
    lis=lis->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to start at the beginning of lis2 each time you go to the next element of lis?  If so, then

```
LINK diffIns(LINK lis,LINK lis2){

    LINK p,head,tail;
    LINK lis2Head = lis2;    // <---
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
    int trovato=0;
    if(lis==NULL && lis2==NULL){return NULL;}
    while(lis!=NULL){
        trovato=0;
        while(lis2!=NULL && trovato==0){
            if(strcmp(lis->d.targa,lis2->d.targa)==0){
                trovato=1;
            }
            else{
                trovato=0;
            }
            lis2=lis2->next;
        }
        if(trovato==0){
            p=newnode();
            p->d=lis->d;
            p->next=NULL;
            if(head==NULL){head=p; tail=p;}
            else{tail->next=p;tail=p;}
        }
    lis=lis->next;
    lis2 = lis2Head;    // <--
    }
    return head;
}
```

This has less impact on your existing code than the above suggestions of keeping lis2 where it is and using the new pointer to actually traverse the second list, but I agree with the above posts.  I generally only modify linked list head pointer parameters in very simple functions.  In more complicated algorithms, leave the head as it is and use a new pointer to go through the list.

Comment: Thank you very very much